# Missing error handler on 'socket'. and typeerror: cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, emit

I'm working on a NodeJS server and I'm trying to use more than one socket.emit but every time I try to do this I get a Missing error handler on 'socket'. and TypeError: cannot read property 'on' of `undefined`. Is there any way to fix this and keep both of the socket.emits?

Some of the code for the server that is broken:

```
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    //send data to client
    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);

    var size = 0;

    //recieve client data
    socket.on('client_data', function(data){
        socket.emit('returnvar', {'returnvar': data.letter});
        socket.broadcast.emit('returnvar', {'returnvar': data.letter});
        process.stdout.write(data.letter);

        var res1 = data.letter.split("",13);

        if(res1 == "h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,y,o,u,t,u" || res1 == "h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,w,w,w,.,y" ){

            process.stdout.write("GOOGOGOOGOGOGOGOOGOGOOGOGOGOGOOGOGO");

            var video = youtubedl(data.letter,
                // Optional arguments passed to youtube-dl.
                ['--format=18'],
                // Additional options can be given for calling `child_process.execFile()`.
                { cwd: __dirname });

            // Will be called when the download starts.
            video.on('info', function(info) {
                console.log('Download started');
                console.log('filename: ' + info._filename);
                console.log('size: ' + info.size);
                size = info.size;
            });

            video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));
        }

        var pos = 0;

        video.on('data', function data(chunk) {
            'use strict';
            pos += chunk.length;

            // `size` should not be 0 here.
            if (size) {
                var percent = (pos / size * 100).toFixed(2);
                process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
                process.stdout.clearLine(1);
                process.stdout.write(percent + '%');
                socket.emit('returnvar1', {'returnvar1': percent + '%'});
                socket.broadcast.emit('returnvar1', {'returnvar1': percent + '%'});
            }
        });

    });
```

[here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLWgc.png)

ok after lots of time just putting random code everywhere i came to this solution:

```
    listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    //send data to client
    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);

    var size = 0;

    //recieve client data
    socket.on('client_data', function(data){
        socket.emit('returnvar', {'returnvar': data.letter});
        socket.broadcast.emit('returnvar', {'returnvar': data.letter});
        process.stdout.write(data.letter);

        var res1 = data.letter.split("",13);

        if(res1 == "h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,y,o,u,t,u" || res1 == "h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,w,w,w,.,y" ){

            process.stdout.write("GOOGOGOOGOGOGOGOOGOGOOGOGOGOGOOGOGO");

            var video = youtubedl(data.letter,
                // Optional arguments passed to youtube-dl.
                ['--format=18'],
                // Additional options can be given for calling `child_process.execFile()`.
                { cwd: __dirname });

            // Will be called when the download starts.
            video.on('info', function(info) {
                console.log('Download started');
                console.log('filename: ' + info._filename);
                console.log('size: ' + info.size);
                size = info.size;
            });


             var pos = 0;

        video.on('data', function data(chunk) {
            'use strict';
            pos += chunk.length;

            // `size` should not be 0 here.
            if (size) {
                var percent = (pos / size * 100).toFixed(2);
                process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
                process.stdout.clearLine(1);
                process.stdout.write(percent + '%');
                socket.emit('returnvar1', {'returnvar1': percent + '%'});
                socket.broadcast.emit('returnvar1', {'returnvar1': percent + '%'});
            }
        });

            video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));
        }



    });
```

Comment: include exact error message

Comment: @suraj99934 what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Include the exact error stack printed on console

Comment: @suraj99934 ok i added a image of the error at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is "socket is not define". Try like below.

```
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('client_data', function(data){ ... }); // here socket is define
    ... 
    //send data to client
    setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: nope i just tried it and it still throws the same error

Comment: With `video` you have a same trouble.

Comment: no as far as i know its only with socket video is part of another and worked before this